# Array realocation without calling to realloc system call

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I assumed that this would show up some error, because array couldn't intialised dynamically in c without `malloc.` But it did work without showing any errors. Is this compiler dependent thing? If possible how can I reallocate memory without using  `realloc` likewise.?

```
#include <stdio.h>
//no error is shown
int main()
{
    int n;
    n=5;
    char ptr[n];
    printf("%d",sizeof(ptr));  
    n=20;
    ptr[n+10];  
    printf("%d",sizeof(ptr));  
}
```

Comment: *VLA* (*Variable Length Arrays*) are supported starting C99 (and became optional in C11). Note, these are allocated on stack and therefore only live in the current function, so you can't treat them same as dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: i came from `C89` where VLA is only allocated on the heap via `malloc()` and reallocated on the heap also via `realloc()`

Comment: Note that `ptr[n+10];` statement does nothing useful, but invokes undefined behavior as it accessing array out of bounds

Comment: using VLA you can do `int n = 5 ; { char ptr[n]; printf("%d",sizeof(ptr)); } n=20; { char ptr[n+10]; printf("%d",sizeof(ptr));  }` so two different vars, not like with *realloc*

Comment: It's allowed from ```C99```. But you can't use ```realloc``` memory for ```ptr```.

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
ptr[n+10];
```

doesn't resize the array - it just attempts to access an element outside of its bounds, the behavior of which is *undefined*.  It *may* result in a runtime error, or it may not.

Despite their name, variable-length arrays cannot be resized once they are defined.  The "variable" in variable-length only means that they can be a different size each time they are defined.

If you want to allocate memory for an array at runtime and then be able to resize that array, then you need to use the `*alloc` routines in the standard library:

```
int n = 5;
char *ptr = malloc( sizeof *ptr * n );
...
n = 20;
char *tmp = realloc( ptr, sizeof *ptr * (n + 10) ); 
if ( tmp )
  ptr = tmp;
```

Note that `sizeof ptr` will only give you the size of a `char *`, not the amount of memory that has been allocated; you'll have to track the array size separately.